# Visual Studio shows errors which do not exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I migrated the code from .Net Core 1.1 to .Net Core 2.0, Visual Studio is showing errors for the classes referenced from other projects (.Net Standard 2.0 now); while, the code can be built without errors from the command line and even the Visual Studio itself!

[image]

> Cannot resolve symbol `Application User`

Is there any work around to fix this?

Comment: Did you close and re-open VS?

Comment: @MartinUllrich Yes, did the same for the solution and the whole VS, still no chance.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Tried this as well, same results. It seams that the same problem existed a couple of months ago, but perhaps it should be solved by now: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/May/15/Upgrading-to-NET-Core-20-Preview.

Comment: are all projects in the same solution? if you're in a git repo, cleaning with `git clean -fdx .` can help. a "clean" doesn't necessarily delete the `obj\project.assets.json` file in all projects. And VS' design time build cache can be tricky..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was somewhere else, and I post it here so maybe others who face the same issue may use it.

The problem was that I set the target framework of the referenced projects to .Net Standard 2.0 during the migration, and my guess is that there has been some incompatibility issues, as when I changed those to .Net Core 2.0 the problem got solved.

Actually this was tricky because I could compile and build the code.